# Spring GetMapping returns view but PostMapping returns error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Absolutely beginner question about Java Spring. This is my controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("ahome")
    public String getHome() {
        System.out.println("get");
        return "home";
    }

    @PostMapping("ahome")
    public String postHome() {
        System.out.println("post");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

"home" is home.html in "views" folder and in my application.properties file there are two lines:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

When I go to "http://localhost:8080/ahome my GetMapping method works and returns view home.html
There is simple form in this view, and when I hit "submit" button in this form it goes to my PostMapping method and it works ("System.out.println("post")) prints "post" BUT instead of returning view home.html it returns an error "Request method 'POST' not supported".

Why is this happening?
What should I do to return view by PostMapping?

Answer (score -1):

YOU should add following to your controller

```
 @GetMapping("home")
    public String getHomePage() {
        System.out.println("post");
        return "home";
    }
```

or 
change the existing method return from home to **ahome**

```
@PostMapping("ahome")
    public String postHome() {
        System.out.println("post");
        return "ahome";
    }
```

Comment: Nope, still it isn't working.
When I've used first solution (with new method "getHomePage") it didn't reach it. App has broken at the same line as previously with error "Request method 'POST' not supported".
When I've used second solution (with changed method "postHome") it also broken down with error "No message available".
I don't understand why "return" in GetMapping is pointing to view, but in PostMapping it isn't.